# SQL SUM based on first two characters of one column, one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, subtotal

I'm fairly new to SQL and have the following dilemma. I have the following  partial table:

```
Account  Description  ShortDescription  Balance
------------------------------------------------
100001   Blah, blah   Blah, blah        28350.68
100020     "            "               2537.35
111000     "            "               86898.12
111001     "            "               63943.63
121000     "            "               55325.68
121012     "            "               65264.35
122000     "            "               94898.85
```

I need to SUM the Balance of all Account starting with the first two digits. So the first two Balance is summed, next two summed, next three summed, etc. Then I need to take those sums and create a grand total.

The end table will include all of the columns, SubTotal, and GrandTotal. I can't figure out a good way to do this; I tried OVER - PARTITION BY with no success (SELECT SUM(Balance) OVER (PARTITION BY Account) AS SubTotal). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think SQL was not designed to handle such requirements. You'd be better off using some king of reporting system to generate subtotals.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way of outputting a table with grand total and subtotals:

```
    -- select individual Rows
    select Account, Description, ShortDescription, Balance from Accounts
union
    -- subtotals
    select 
        substring(Account, 1, 2) as Account, 
        substring(Account, 1, 2) + ' Subtotal' as Description,
        '' as ShortDescription,
        sum(Balance) as Balance
    from Accounts
    group by substring(Account, 1, 2)
union
    -- grand total
    select 
        '' as Account,
        'Grand Total' as Description,
        '' as ShortDescription,
        sum(Balance) as Balance
    from Accounts
-- order all records to give the illusion of interlaced subtotals/grand total
order by Account desc
```

However, I think the optimal solution would be to have a plain select from the table and use a reporting tool (such as SQL Server Reporting Services) handle the total/subtotals.

Please not that in the above statement I assumed that the `Account` column is of type `char`/`varchar`. If it is declared as `int` or other numeric type, you should add the appropriate cast/convert transformations. (all data sets in a `union` must have the same number of columns and the same data types)

Comment: Thank you w0lf! This worked great! In the real world I would have used a reporting tool; that's what they are for. But this is query training for me. I now can do research on UNION; I've never seen that before. Many thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad that helped. Here's the TSQL documentation for `UNION`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that the initial problem was that writing partitions correctly is a bit difficult, since the syntax is a bit of a pain. If I undestand what you are looking for (all values and totals in the individual rows,) as a simple alternative to what w0lf provided, here is what may be a quicker solution:

```
    Select *, SUM(Balance) OVER (PARTITION BY substring(Account, 1, 2)) as Subtotal, 
  Sum(Balance) over(Partition by 1) as Total
    from dbo.Accounts
```

This gives each of the original columns (*), in addition to a subtotal column, and a total column, using sums over the partitions.

I used the following structure and your data, if you get any errors this might be helpful:

```
   CREATE TABLE dbo.Accounts (Account varchar(10), [Description] varchar(10),
ShortDescription varchar(10), Balance money)  GO

    INSERT INTO Accounts (Account, Description, ShortDescription, Balance) VALUES  
    (100001, 'Blah', 'Blah2', 28350.68),(100020, 'Blah', 'Blah2', 2537.35),
    (111000, 'Blah', 'Blah2', 86898.12),(111001, 'Blah', 'Blah2', 63943.63),
    (121000, 'Blah', 'Blah2', 55325.68),(121012, 'Blah', 'Blah2', 65264.35),
    (122000, 'Blah', 'Blah2', 94898.85)
```

As an addendum, if the Accounts are stored as numbers, you can use substring(cast(Account as varchar(max)), 1, 2))  instead of substring(Account, 1, 2).

Comment: Thank you David! I thought there might be a way to use OVER - PARTITION BY but it wasn't working. While w0lf's is better formatted, I'm hanging on to this code for its simplicity. Two things I've learned today - UNION and SUBSTRING! Thanks again!